# How to add an artwork image to mp3

Tags: perl, mp3, id3

To add an artwork image to mp3 file in Perl, what library should I use? Sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use this library:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/MP3::Tag::ID3v2](http://metacpan.org/pod/MP3%3a%3aTag%3a%3aID3v2)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use MP3::Tag;
use Image::Magick;

$file = “file.mp3″;
$jpg = “file.jpg”;

my $image = new Image::Magick;
if (my $x = $image->Read($jpg)) {
print “Couldn’t read image ‘$jpg’\n”;
}else{
$imagedata = $image->ImageToBlob(magick => jpg);
undef $image;
}

my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($file);
$mp3->get_tags();

$mp3->{ID3v2}->remove_tag() if exists $mp3->{ID3v2};
$mp3->{ID3v1}->remove_tag() if exists $mp3->{ID3v1};

my $id3v2 = $mp3->new_tag(“ID3v2″);
$id3v2->add_frame(“TALB”, $album);
$id3v2->add_frame(“TPE1″, $artist);
$id3v2->add_frame(“TIT2″, $title);
$id3v2->add_frame(“APIC”, chr(0×0), ‘image/jpg’, chr(0×0), ‘Cover (front)’, $imagedata);
$id3v2->write_tag();

my $id3v1 = $mp3->new_tag(“ID3v1″);
$id3v1->song($title);
$id3v1->artist($artist);
$id3v1->album($album);
$id3v1->write_tag();
$mp3->close();
```

Some people are reporting that it generates corrupt mp3, don't really know if it was fixed already, but if not, comment out the line:

```
$flags = chr(128) if $tag_data =~ s/\xFF(?=[\x00\xE0-\xFF])/\xFF\x00/g;
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: If there isn't a reason to point to a specific version of a module, please use one of the non version specific URLs. http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/MP3::Tag::ID3v2 http://search.cpan.org/dist/MP3-Tag/ http://metacpan.org/module/MP3::Tag::ID3v2 http://p3rl.org/MP3::Tag::ID3v2 (which currently redirects to the metacpan.org site)